# Тестирование работы контроллеров с несколькими БД

Tags: laravel, phpunit

Laravel 5.4
Необходимо протестировать метод контроллера, производящего запись в 2 БД.
Проблема возникла с подключением второй БД для теста.

С первой БД проблем не возникло, прописал в phpunit.xml:

```
<phpunit>
<php>
<env name="APP_ENV" value="testing"/>
        <env name="CACHE_DRIVER" value="array"/>
        <env name="SESSION_DRIVER" value="array"/>
        <env name="QUEUE_DRIVER" value="sync"/>
        <env name="DB_CONNECTION" value="sqlite" />
        <env name="DB_DATABASE" value=":memory:" />
</php>
</phpunit>
```

Для второй БД добавляю туда же:

```
<env name="OTHER_DB_CONNECTION" value="sqliteother" />
<env name="OTHER_DB_DATABASE" value=":memory:" />
```

В database.php:

```
'sqlite' => [
            'driver' => 'sqlite',
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', database_path('database.sqlite')),
            'prefix' => '',
        ],

'sqliteother' => [
            'driver' => 'sqlite',
            'database' => env('OTHER_DB_DATABASE', database_path('database.sqlite')),
            'prefix' => '',
        ],
```

При запросе ко второй БД пишет:
PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [1044] Access denied for user '%otheruser%'@'%host%' to database ':memory:' in /var/www/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connectors/Connector.php on line 68

Если использовать только первую БД, то проблем не возникает.
Обращение ко всем БД выполнено через модели. (тут конкретно работа с 2-мя моделями с разным коннекшеном)
По существу ничего в нагуглить не смог.

Comment: а если подключиться только ко второй бд?

Comment: @Rikaz если только вторую бд прописать, то она работает. Тут вопрос не в работе по отдельности, а по работе вместе. То есть, первая БД создается в памяти (':memory:') только для тестирования. Как корректно расположить туда вторую БД?

Comment: Создай 2 файла и пиши туда зачем тебе  memory? Но судя по [этой](https://sqlite.org/inmemorydb.html) статье можно сделать 2 `file:memdb1?mode=memory` и `file:memdb2?mode=memory`, но я чет не уверен что такое злодеяние прокатит

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Разобрался.
В database.php:

```
'sqlite' => [
    'driver' => 'sqlite',
    'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', database_path('database.sqlite')),
    'prefix' => '',
],

'sqliteother' => [
    'driver' => 'sqlite',
    'database' => env('OTHER_DB_DATABASE', database_path('sqliteother.sqlite')),
    'prefix' => '',
],
```

При этом, в модели, которая использует соединение не по-умолчанию, имя соединения нужно указать через переменную окружения. Но напрямую не получилось, поэтому сделал через константу:
В bootstrap/app.php добавил:

```
defined('OTHER_DB_CONNECTION') or define('OTHER_DB_CONNECTION', env('OTHER_DB_CONNECTION', 'other'));
```

В модель добавил вместо:

```
protected $connection = 'other';
```

вот это:

```
protected $connection = OTHER_DB_CONNECTION;
```

В миграциях для создания таблицы в другой БД нужно указывать имя БД:

```
Schema::connection(OTHER_DB_CONNECTION)->create(....)
```